# Asking was formula

Tags: past-tense

I was reading the articles from Dailymail, and I found this sentence: "Matthew Perry was accompanied by a female friend on Thursday morning as he stepped out for coffee in Los Angeles". I wondered, why using "was accompanied" with ed, isn't formula was + ing? Why with verb too?

Comment: These are two different tenses. He _was accompanied by_ a friend - his friend _was accompanying_ him.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaking this for a past progressive tense, but it is not. It is the past simple *passive*.

There is the past progressive active, which emphasizes the subject "Perry:"

> Perry was accompanying someone

There is the past progressive passive, which puts the emphasis on Perry's companion:

> Perry was *being* accompanied *by* someone

Note how in both forms, the word immediately following "was" is a gerund.

Then there is the past simple active:

> Perry accompanied someone

And finally the past simple passive:

> Perry *was* accompanied *by* someone

Just like the past progressive passive added both "being" and "by," the past simple passive adds both "was" and "by." The "was" is **not** being used in the same way here as it is used in the progressive tense.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation. i check the past simple passive on my book and now i get it. Thank you so much, you are a live saver 

Answer (score 0):

"Was accompanied" is legal here, it's just suggesting past tense. This [was + past-tense-verb + by] structure is generally allowed: "The man was hurt by the accusations", "the child was spoiled by his parents", "the CEO was chastised by the board of trustees". "Matthew Perry was accompanying a female friend..." would also be appropriate, but shifts the emphasis to something he's doing for his friend vs. something his friend is doing for him.

Comment: thank you so much, i get now.